# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases Calls: lm -> lm.fit

Tags: r, linear-regression, eval, lm

I am trying to run an R application, but I receive the following **first** error :

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>     0 (non-NA) cases
>   Calls: lm -> lm.fit

The code which generates the error is :

```
pppb = lm(Exchange.rate.change ~ Inflation.difference)
```

I am new to R and is really hard for me to find the mistake, so any help it is really appreciated. This is a minimal data set:

```
Country Inflation.difference    Exchange.rate.change    Developed
Australia   -1.235100000e+000   -3.187000000e+000   1.000000000e+000
Austria 1.550800000e+000    1.478100000e+000    1.000000000e+000
Belgium 1.037100000e+000    3.950000000e-002    1.000000000e+000
Canada  4.610000000e-002    -1.641600000e+000   1.000000000e+000
Chile   -1.841260000e+001   -2.063290000e+001   0.000000000e+000
```

This is the minimal runnable code necessary to reproduce the error :

```
ppp = read.table("test.dat",sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
attach(ppp)
Developed[Developed==1] = "Developed"
newppp = ppp[ppp$Country!="Brazil",]
attach(newppp)
developed = newppp[Developed==1,]
attach(developed)
pppb = lm(Exchange.rate.change ~ Inflation.difference)
```

This is the **second** error I get :

> The following object is masked *by* .GlobalEnv:
>           Developed
>       The following objects are masked from ppp:
>           Country, Developed, Exchange.rate.change, Inflation.difference
>       The following object is masked *by* .GlobalEnv:
>           Developed
>       The following objects are masked from newppp:
>           Country, Developed, Exchange.rate.change, Inflation.difference
>       The following objects are masked from ppp:
>           Country, Developed, Exchange.rate.change, Inflation.difference 
>   Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>         0 (non-NA) cases
>       Calls: lm -> lm.fit
>       Execution halted
>       `

Comment: I think the error message says that you do not have any data to fit the model on (or all are NA). Could you post a reproducible example with the data you use?

Comment: is any of your columns all NAs? can do dput(head(Exchange.rate.change,5)) and dput(head(Inflation.difference,5)) and paste the output as part of your post?

Comment: `dput(head(Exchange.rate.change,5)) - c(-3.187, 1.4781, 0.0395, -1.6416, -20.6329)`
`dput(head(Inflation.difference,5)) - c(-1.2351, 1.5508, 1.0371, 0.0461, -18.4126)`
So they don't seem to be NA.

Comment: Here is a part of data I am using :

`Country Inflation difference Exchange rate change Developed

Australia -1.235100000e+000 -3.187000000e+000 1.000000000e+000

Austria 1.550800000e+000 1.478100000e+000 1.000000000e+000

Belgium 1.037100000e+000 3.950000000e-002 1.000000000e+000`

Comment: In order to make your question reproducible and thus answerable, we need minimal, self-contained code and data so that we are able to reproduce your problem on our machine. Please follow these simple guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** if you just do

```
lm(Exchange.rate.change ~ Inflation.difference, data =ppp,
      subset=Developed==1)
```

immediately after reading the data (without any of the other code) it seems to work fine.

Or, if you want to subset the data you could do

```
developed <- ppp[ppp$Developed==1, ] 
## or developed <- subset(ppp, Developed == 1)
lm(Exchange.rate.change ~ Inflation.difference, data = developed)
```

---

```
attach(ppp)
```

`attach()` is generally **not** recommended; instead, use the `data=` argument

```
Developed[Developed==1] = "Developed"
```

This is weird (and doesn't affect the later results, I think); it converts the numeric vector to character (so the contents are either "Developed" or "0")

```
newppp = ppp[ppp$Country!="Brazil",]
```

Brazil isn't actually in the data set you showed us, so this doesn't do anything in this particular case

```
attach(newppp)
```

`attach()`ing multiple times will make things even more confusing (this is the source of the warnings you get)

```
developed = newppp[Developed==1,]
```

This is where things go wrong. The current copy of `Developed` in your workspace is

```
[1] "Developed" "Developed" "Developed" "Developed" "0"
```

because of your previous statement.  None of these values is equal to 1, so `developed` is now empty (zero rows).

```
attach(developed)
pppb = lm(Exchange.rate.change ~ Inflation.difference)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Try starting with a clean session ...